# Simple linux router with two NICs

Tags: linux, router

I tried following these guides without success:

- [Setting up an Ubuntu Wired/Wireless Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router)
- [Configure Ubuntu as a Router](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html)

I have a small Linux box with two NICs:

Cable modem/router (out of my control) ----> LINUX BOX w/ two NICs:

- **eth2** => connected to the Internet, gets a 192.168.1.124 address automatically from the cable modem upstream
- **eth3** => I want to plug into this jack and automatically get internet (either on a laptop or AP) -- assuming need a DHCP server here?

I gave up on my settings and am starting from scratch. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**nano -w /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
EMPTY
```

**nano -w /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

**nano -w /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**

```
INTERFACES=""
```

**And here is my ip route:**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth2  metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.124
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux router share internet between eth2 to eth3](http://serverfault.com/questions/619330/linux-router-share-internet-between-eth2-to-eth3)

Comment: supposing you **do** want to separate the networks, why don't you just use existing firewall distros, like IPCop or pfSense? It's way easier and problably more secure, because it's easier to set up.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure your internal interface (eth3) with a static address so **/etc/network/interfaces** will look something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address 10.10.10.1
network 10.10.10.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.10.10.255
```

You will probably want to enable a DHCP server for the internal interface unless you want to manually configure the clients on your network.

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**:

```
INTERFACES="eth3"
```

Your **dhcpd.conf** would look something like:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.10.10.255;
option routers 10.10.10.1;
option domain-name-servers x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y;

subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 10.10.10.10 10.10.10.100;
}
```

Replace **x.x.x.x** and **y.y.y.y** with your ISP's DNS servers

Restart DHCPD:

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

At this point a client should be furnished with an IP in the range of your internal network and should be able to ping the gateway (eth3) and get a reply:

`ping 10.10.10.1`

Next try pinging eth2:

`ping 192.168.1.124`

Ping the interface on the inside of the cable modem:

`ping 192.168.1.1`

If that's all successful you can start concentrating on getting the IP forwarding and masquerading working.

Comment: Thank you for this super detailed response.


I followed exactly your settings and I'm back to my usual roadblock:

My client (laptop) plugged into eth3 gets a 10.10.10.10 address, looks great. From that laptop I can ping 10.10.10.1 (eth3 gateway), 192.168.1.124 (eth2), but I can NOT ping 192.168.1.1.

Here is my ip route now:

    default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth2  metric 100
    10.10.10.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.1
    169.254.0.0/16 dev eth3  scope link  metric 1000
    192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.124

Comment: Also on the actual Linux box, I can NOT ping eth2 from eth3 (ping -I eth3 192.168.1.124 does not work).

Comment: Interesting enough, I followed the instructions for Shorewall routing and somehow it worked @ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShorewallBasics. It's frustrating--I wish I knew what was going on with the instructions in this thread. I'd still appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want seperate networks on your linux box? If that is the case you don't need routing. You would *bridge* the two NICs and go for it. You also don't need a DHCP server because your cable modem acts as one (eth2 gets an IP). You need `bridge-utils` for creating a bridge.
[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BridgingNetworkInterfaces)

Comment: @black-sensei 

For now, I am trying to get basic router functionality working on Linux--I'd like to turn it into a proxy server/captive portal later on. But that's looking to be too advanced if I can't even get the basic stuff working!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind you might want to use already built ones like clearOS or pfsense or zentyal although clearOS and zentyal do a little bit more than routing and have community licenses .
I thought this would get you going if you have tight timeline and target to meet.